# Swipe to back navigation not working for Localization app

Tags: ios, localization, uinavigationcontroller

In my app I'm using two languages English and Arabic. When I change my language from one to another the swipe to back navigation is working as my previous language.

Eg: English swipe left to right, Arabic swipe right to left. But in my case English popping right to left, Arabic popping left to right. This happens for the first time of the app launch after changing language. For the next time its working fine.

After changing language the user need to restart the app. I use this below code to set the language,

In main.m

```
        if ([languageSelected isEqualToString:@"en_US"]) {
            NSArray* languages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:languages forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
        } else if ([languageSelected isEqualToString:@"ar"]) {                
            NSArray* languages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ar", nil];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:languages forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
        }
```

Could anyone give some suggestion?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I think its something to do with setting the rootviewcontroller with navigationcontroller.

Comment: Could you please explain briefly?

Comment: I think your viewcontroller is not embedded with a navigationcontroller at the time of launch thats why swipe to back navigation is not working for you.

Comment: if its not embedded then pushing view controller also not to work right? But its working fine

Comment: Actually I'm facing difficulty without the whole code. But I can surely tell you the upper mentioned code has nothing to do with the navigation.

Comment: ok I will try my best.

Comment: @Poles I found the solution please check below.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, we need to set language at the time of app terminates like below

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
        if ([languageSelected isEqualToString:@"en_US"]) {
            LocalizationSetLanguage(@"en");
            NSArray* languages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:languages forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
        } else if ([languageSelected isEqualToString:@"ar"]) {
            LocalizationSetLanguage(@"ar");
            NSArray* languages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ar", nil];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:languages forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
        }
}
```

Hope some one get use of it.

Comment: Great job. But how this code controls the navigation? I'm just asking...

Comment: Before I set the language in main.m is not doing any effect on navigation may be it takes some time. So I did it at the time of termination.